# Change vTiger 6.1.0 Products Popup Columns

Tags: php, vtiger

I am trying to modify a couple of the columns shown in the add product popup.  By default there are Product Name, Part Number, Unit Price, Commission Rate, Qty/Unit, and Action.

I would like to:
1.   remove the Action Field.
2.  change the Qty/Unit to the Qty in Stock.

Any ideas on how I would go about that.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous version of vtiger, you had to change in modules/Products/Products.php file arrays $search_fields and $search_fields_name